# Using variables inside and outside of getJSON calls with Shopify and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, shopify

I'm trying to do some calculations on the product types in the cart in Shopify.  This requires 2 getJSON calls that are related.  Below is the code that I currently have, obviously it has some problems and I don't know the best way to overcome them.  I don't want to turn async off, as that seems like a hacky way to do it.

```
var smallCount, mediumCount, largeCount; 

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) //Gets all the items in a cart.
  {

    smallCount = 0; mediumCount = 0; largeCount = 0;

    //Go through each item in the cart.
    for(var i = 0; i < cart.items.length; i++)
    {   
            //For each item we're going to grab the json info
            //Specifically looking for the product type
        $.getJSON('/products/'+cart.items[i].handle+'.js', function(product) { 
            if(product.type == "Small")
            { smallCount += cart.items[i].quantity; } //These don't work
            else if (product.type == "Medium")
            { mediumCount += cart.items[i].quantity; } //These don't work
            else if (product.type == "Large")
            { largeCount += cart.items[i].quantity; } //These don't work
        }); 
    }

    //Here or below I'd like to do some analysis on the product types in the cart.
    //I want to get all of the counts and then do some work with them.
    mathHappening = smallCount + mediumCount + largeCount;  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/. May be this is what you want to use.